# взаимодействие SearchView с ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть Activity с SearchView и ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.x.searchwithlistview.MainActivity">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="418dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код:

```
package com.example.x.searchwithlistview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
    ListView listView;
    SearchView searchView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        names.add("StackOverflow");
        names.add("Stack Exchange");
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
    }
}
```

**Как** сделать , что бы при вводе текста , из ListView удалялись item не равны тексту или не равны началу SearchView ?

Comment: пусть адаптер ресайклера реализует интерфейс filterable, и собственно в коллбеках серчвью у адаптера вызываете getFilter().filter("query")

Comment: @SviatVolkov Был бы Вам благодарен , если бы Вы это оформили в виде ответа с кодом.

Comment: писать много) держите лучше статью которая всё подробно объясняет https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

Comment: какой адаптер используется?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Добавил код в  вопросе!